# Can I download Movie Creator using .exe file?

Tags: windows-10

I go to [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/movie-creator-free-video-editor/9nblggh4wwjr#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) (Microsoft website) to download **Movie Creator** software but when I click **Get**, it opens a page or something like an app called **Store** and it says: The server stumbled. Error code: 0x80072EE7.

I can't download the software this way. Moreover, I wouldn't like the invasion of my computer by companies. Is there a place where I can download an .exe file?

Comment: No there is not, you will have to wait for Microsoft to resolve the website problem.

Comment: @Moab I'll download another software :) Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Movie Creator is now called Story Remix and is included in the
Windows Photos app, so does not need any installation since it is already installed
if your Windows 10 is up to date.

Start the Photos app from the Start menu,
click the Collections tab, choose the photos and videos you want in your video,
click Add to (+), select video and
give the video a name and the editor will show up .

For more information see :

- [Windows Movie Maker is back: how to use Windows 10's hidden video editor](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/windows-movie-maker-is-back-how-to-use-windows-10s-hidden-video-editor)
- [How to get started with Story Remix in Photos on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-start-using-photos-story-remix-experience-windows-10)
- [Story Remix for Windows 10 Fall Creators Update Preview](https://www.groovypost.com/reviews/story-remix-windows-10-fall-creators-update-preview/)